# Tabbed icons & Keyboard not appearing in text field in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, icons, tabbed

I am working in Xcode 6 in swift. I am using the default UITabBarItem tab icons which are appearing in Main.storyboard, but are not appearing in the simulator (I am using the default images -- nothing uploaded). In addition, the keyboard is not appearing after touching into a text field. I am getting the following error:

Could not load the " " image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "Project Name".

Note that this error is only happened after a segue into the tab bar controller. It is working correctly in prior views.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a bad layout which is pushing the tab icons off the screen. Suggest you use the Resolve AutoLayout Issues and check it out. Can't comment on the second issue without the code.

Comment: Thanks for responding - the title is appearing, but the icon above the title is not showing up so I do not think it is a layout issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just `clear the constraints` and then click on the `Add Missing Constraints`